# Are memcomputing and neuromorphic computing the same thing?

Tags: memory-hardware

As the title reads, I’m just trying to understand if there is any difference between memcomputing and neuromorphic computing. If so, what are they?

Memcomputing: https://www.popularmechanics.com/technology/a16308/memcomputer-quantum-computing-alternative/

Answer (score 1):

No, they are not the same thing. They share similarities, in that they are both brain inspired approaches. But this is where the similarities end.

To avoid going into too much detail, I'll explain it with this analogy:

Imagine you're a civilization trying to figure out flight and you're presented with an airplane (analogous to the brain) that you know can fly.
The neuromorphic computing people are doing something akin to dismembering the airplane and trying out individual components of it to see if it can make you fly. A bit like taking a wing of the airplane and throwing it down a cliff to see how well it flies. Eventually you might figure out that the wing is able to generate some lift, provided some other things are present (like thrust and a second wing), but it'll take some trial and error and you're not really seeing the big picture until you've solved the puzzle of "what are the essential components and how to they contribute to flight?"

MemComputing takes a bit of a different approach. It's more like getting a working theory of flight first, using that to figure out some potentially essential components, and trying to use that to fly even if it doesn't reproduce that working airplane exactly.

The way to do this is to try to understand computation from a physics perspective. In doing so, we can develop a new computational paradigm separate from the Turing paradigm. We can understand why some problems are exponentially difficult to solve by mapping the problem onto physical systems that need to be simulated and realize that the origin of the difficulty in computation can be understood as long range correlations within the problem statement.

Take for instance the 3SAT problem, which can be generalized quite nicely from. For 3SAT, you're given a number $N$ of Boolean variables, $v_i$, as well as a problem statement with clauses containing these $v_i$ which need to be satisfied. The difficulty here is that each variable in a clause could appear in some distant other clause, meaning that flipping it to try and satisfy a clause would have immediate consequences at long "distances" in a completely different clause. So you can think of 3SAT as being difficult precisely because of such long range correlations.

This is a bit of an issue because Turing based computation has a fundamental bottleneck in the processing operation, since a processing step is completely blind to the operations of other processing units during the processing step. So there is no way to have information transfer during the computational step. Yet it would clearly be helpful from an information flow point of view to have such correlations that allow the more frustrating operations to be suppressed and the less frustrating operations to be less suppressed. This would then hopefully lead to a more efficient exploration of the decision tree.

It turns our that physical systems with memory have the kind of long-range correlation that can be useful here. This is why it would be appropriate to call MemComputing a computation **in and with memory**, because information isn't just stored in the same location where the processing occurs, but memory is also essential in driving the system towards a solution efficiently.

In the interest of brevity, I've glossed over some really important and interesting details in my answer here. For more details I would recommend the textbook [MemComputing: Fundamentals and Applications](https://academic.oup.com/book/42003) by Max Di Ventra (full disclosure: I work in Di Ventra's research group).